# Predicting the price of a stock via regression model

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to predict the closing price of a stock on a given day given opening price, the highest value and lowest value for that day. I just wanted to check if this model sounds alright:

$$ClosingPrice_{t}=\alpha_1 \cdot OpeningPrice_{t}+\alpha_2 \cdot HighPrice_{t}+\alpha_3 \cdot LowPrice_{t}+\varepsilon_t$$

I plan on using ridge regression as I suspect there will be multicollinearity between some of these variables.

Any feedback or thoughts on my model would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me denote the closing price $C$, the opening price $O$, the high price $H$ and the low price $L$.
Some thoughts:

1. This is not an ARIMA model (as stated in the original title), this is a regression model.
2. This will not be a feasible predictive model since $H$ and $L$ are not available until the trading closes, when also $C$ becomes available.
3. You may introduce some coefficient restrictions to ensure the closing price always is inbetween $H$ and $L$ (possibly equal to one of them).
4. Excluding the intercept as you have done may or may not be a good idea. Including it could make the interpretation more straightforward. Also, for the sake of interpretation you could consider using $H-O$ and $L-O$ as regressors in place of $H$ and $L$, respectively.
5. Stock prices are nonstationary, integrated processes. Running a simple regression with a bunch of integrated variables will yield OLS coefficients with nonstandard properties. Since $C$, $O$, $H$ and $L$ will almost certainly be cointegrated, a vector error correction model (VECM) seems to be the relevant model. It also has the virtue of being suited for forecasting. If you apply it on logarithmic data, you will have logarithmic returns on the left hand side, which is quite convenient.

Comment: I plan on using the idea in point 5 to obtain my model. I plan on using $Returnsclosingprice_{t} = \alpha_1 \cdot Returnsopeningprice_{t} +\alpha_2 \cdot Returnshighprice_{t} + \alpha_3 \cdot ReturnsLowPrice_{t}$

Comment: I take it that $differencedopeningprice_{t} = openingprice_{t}- openigprice_{t-1}$ and so on for each of the variables on the right hand side. However, I am slightly confused as to the relationship between $differencedopeningprice_{t}$ and $Returnsopeningprice_{t}$ and similarly with the other variables.

Comment: When it comes to stock returns, it is quite usual (and comfortable) to work with log-returns such as `diff(log(x))` for a stock price `x`. Although I did not include this in point 5., it could be more meaningful to work with `diff(log(C))`, `diff(log(O))`, `log(H)-log(O)` and `log(L)-log(O)` where the latter two would be used instead of `diff(log(H))` and `diff(log(L))`. You could use lags of `log(H)-log(O)` and `log(L)-log(O)` to make your model operational for predictions (otherwise see the problem identified in point 2.).

Comment: Thank you. So, I will not be dealing with the returns per se? Also, do you think it is necessary I use a Ride Regression, as there is likely to be multicollinearity between these variables or will a simple multilinear regression suffice?

Comment: When it comes to prediction (in contrast to explanatory modelling), ridge regression may be worth trying even if there is no severe multicollinearity. Note that I am talking about **ridge** regression, which I suppose is what you meant when you wrote "Ride Regression".

Comment: Got it, thanks. One last question I have is, and I apologize as this is fairly simple when you said `log(x)` is the log returns for stock price `x`, do you mean `log(O) = log(P_open_t - P_open_t/P_open_t)`? And `log(H) = log(P_high_t - P_high_t/P_high_t)` and so on? I guess I am confused as to what log-returns means when we don't use the actual closing price.

Comment: For any variable $x_t$, its log-return is $\text{log}(x_t)-\text{log}(x_{t-1})=\text{log}(\frac{x_t}{x_{t-1}})$ For any variable `x` (a vector of length `T` in R), its log-return is `diff(log(x))` (a vector of length `T-1` in R).

Comment: If I were trying to predict, the **next days** closing price based on the closing price, opening price, etc. of the previous day, wouldn't I use the same model as above, except now each of the variables on the RHS would have to be predicted via their own ARIMA models?

Comment: Either their own univariate ARIMA models or a multivariate model such as VAR to include all of them (the latter is perhaps more common).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help. I have one last question, if I may. If I was to add the number of news articles associated with a stock as a factor into this model, how do you think I could look to predict the number of news articles on `t+1` given all the data for news articles upto `t`? I was thinking of weighting more recent no of news articles heavily, but dont know how to do this and fear this could result in a constant upward trend in news, so dont believe my model for news is correct.

Comment: Or I could take the moving average of number of news articles and have the `number of news articles on a particular day - the moving average` as a factor in the overall model. Does this make sense?

Comment: I recognized that VECM was actually the relevant model and edited the answer. You can include exogenous regressors such as `news` there, too. To make the model a feasible prediction model, `news` will have to be lagged. For predictions of more than one step ahead, VECM can be reiterated using predictions as the new inputs (appending predictions to end of the data vectors) without reestimating the model coefficients. You will also have to predict `news` to supply the relevant lags of `news` for prediction with the VECM. You can use a naive no-change forecast or ARIMA or something else for that.

Comment: Why not add predictors based on the industry of the stock? Also, adding dummy variables to account for various aspects of seasonality in your time series seems justified. Lags of the dependent variable will also add predictive power and insight.

Comment: @DJohnson, seasonal effects in stock prices are a thing of the past. They have long since been spotted by traders and "arbitraged away" so that seasonal effects essentially no longer exist. (The same is likely true for lags of the dependent variable, which also would mean a VECM model would be of no predictive use.) Meanwhile, your suggestion of industry-specific predictors sounds more reasonable.

Comment: @RichardHardy  I'm a current analyst of daily stock prices and am finding day of week effects. So, to me, your "arbitrage" assumption is worth challenging with evidence from your own stocks time series.

Comment: @DJohnson, fair enough. "In God we trust, everyone else bring data." I just wanted to note that in mature and liquid exchanges these effects are long gone. (I used to work as a stock analyst myself a few years ago, so I am somewhat familiar with the subject.)

Comment: @RichardHardy  Clearly, you are well informed. My only real point is that there a million "myths" on the Street and you can believe half of them...you just don't know which half to believe. Therefore, verify.