# Issue when building VAR model using Python

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

Building on my Question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178531/predicting-the-price-of-a-stock-via-regression-model) which involved predicting the closing price of a stock given the previous days closing price, opening price, high price, low price and the number of articles associated with the stock. I have been recommended to use a VAR Model due to the possibility of Cointegration between the exogenous variables. And I am differencing the terms to remove non-stationarity and also using returns rather than prices in the model. The model looks as follows:

$log(Close_{t}) = A_1*log(Close_{t-1}) + .... + A_p*log(Close_{t-p}) + u_{t}$ where I have a 21*5 multivariate VAR Time series, as I only have 21 data points and have closing price, opening price, high price, low price and the number of articles as the exogenous variables. So, I do this in Pythn and am using the `statsmodels` module using the documentation provided [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html#var).

The data I am using is as follows:

```
          date   sym    open      high       low     close  newscount
0   2014.08.01   IBM  191.20  191.6700  188.8400  189.1800          3
1   2014.08.01  NFLX  418.81  427.7600  412.5100  425.4200          0
2   2014.08.01   WMT   73.50   73.8900   73.2100   73.5500          3
3   2014.08.04   IBM  189.00  190.4800  188.6000  189.6300          2
```

Some of the code I have is given below where `df_IBM_training` is the dataframe associated with IBM and only considers the training set:

```
regressor_1 = np.log(df_IBM_training['close'])
regressor_2 = np.log(df_IBM_training.open) - np.log(df_IBM_training.open.shift(1))
regressor_3 = np.log(df_IBM_training.high) - np.log(df_IBM_training.open) 
regressor_4 = np.log(df_IBM_training.low) - np.log(df_IBM_training.open)
regressor_5 = df_IBM_training.newscount
```

`model = statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR(X_IBM)`
where

`X_IBM = [10**(regressor_1), 10**(regressor_2), 10**(regressor_3), 10**(regressor_4), 10**(regressor_5)] #Variables`

But, I then attempt to determine the lag of the model and get the error `numpy.linalg.linalg.linalgerror: 8th leading minor not positive definite`, **which suggests to me that the model might be wrong or that I am not using the statsmodel VAR correctly and I need help in this regard**:

`model.select_order(2)`

Thank You

Note: I realize I was told to use VECM, but this is not available in Python and unfortunately I am not well versed in R, so I thought using VAR my not be too bad.

Comment: @RichardHardy I was wondering if you could please provide some help with this issue.

Comment: You can't predict tomorrow's closing price. [Forget about it](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/economic-sciences/laureates/2013/fama-facts.html). You can "predict" to a certain degree the long term return, I means months or years ahead. Nothing you build is going to predict tomorrow's price.

Comment: @Aksakal I dont dispute that. Its more of a thought experiment than anything else.

Comment: Are your time series only 21-observations long? That is actually a very, very short sample. Also, is VECM really not available i Python? That's a pity. But you could assume that each pair of variables $C$, $O$, $H$, $L$ (as in my previous answer) is cointegrated with a cointegration vector (1,-1) (that is, the difference between any pair is stationary), so you could manually build the error correction terms and supply them (lagged by 1) as exogenous regressors. The model would be readily suited for forecasting one step ahead. You would need a little work to forecast more than one step ahead.

Comment: The VARX model with error correction terms (i.e. the manually-built VECM) as indicated in the above comment should have as many equations as there are endogenous variables -- if you intend to forecast more than one step ahead. The variables should be of the form $\Delta \text{log}(X)$ rather than $\text{log}(X)$, i.e. log-returns, except for the error correction terms that will be $\text{log}(C)-\text{log}(O)$, $\text{log}(C)-\text{log}(H)$, and $\text{log}(C)-\text{log}(L)$ (all other cointegrated pairs can be expressed in terms of these three, thus these three should suffice).

Comment: Aksakal is most likely right, and I would not put my money on a VECM to forecast stock prices, but why not play along in this thought experiment. I don't know Python, but what might be going wrong (why you are getting an error) is (1) you are running out of degrees of freedom (too few data points, too many parameters to be estimated) or (2) you somehow got perfectly multicollinear variables (if you used not only logs of the original variables but also differences between them such as $\text{log}(H)-\text{log}(C)$ and $\text{log}(L)-\text{log}(C)$). But it might be something else, too.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks again. So, after thinking about what you've said I see the regression as being as follows, given I only need to predict one step ahead. $$log(C_{t}) = log(C_{t−1})- log(O_{t−1})+log(C_{t−1})-log(H_{t−1}) +\\ log(C_{t−1})-log(L_{t−1})+log(C_{t−1})-log(C_{t−2})+ +log(O_{t−1})−log(O_{t−2})+ \varepsilon_{t-1}.$$ Is this right?

Comment: Why are you using vector models if you're forecasting only one variable?

Comment: @Aksakal I thought it was necessary as each of the other variables have their own time series? Also, I may be incorrect with my times for the variables on the RHS. They may actually each need to be moved up by a period of time of 1. So, the first variable on the RHS would be $log(C_{t})$

Comment: If you model variables together then vector models are necessary

Comment: @Aksakal Okay. So, I need to use the VECM as was suggested then. Does my model in the previous comment seem appropriate?

Comment: Aksakal's suggestion to use only one equation will only work for one-step-ahead forecasting. For multitple-step-ahead forecasts you will need a vector model. The model you presented in the comment is not OK. Look at how VECMs look in general and look at my comments (especially the one including $\Delta \text{log}(X)$)

Comment: Here is one equation of a VECM(2): $$\Delta \text{log}(C_t)=\alpha_{1,1}(\text{log}(C)-\text{log}(O))+\\\alpha_{1,2}(\text{log}(C)-\text{log}(H))+\alpha_{1,3}(\text{log}(C)-\text{log}(L))+\gamma_{1,11}\Delta \text{log}(C_{t-1})+\\\gamma_{1,12} \Delta\text{log}(O_{t-1})+\gamma_{1,13} \Delta\text{log}(H_{t-1})+\gamma_{1,14} \Delta \text{log}(L_{t-1})+\gamma_{2,11} \Delta \text{log}(C_{t-2})+\\\gamma_{2,12} \Delta \text{log}(O_{t-2})+\gamma_{2,13} \Delta \text{log}(H_{t-2})+\gamma_{2,14}\Delta \text{log}(L_{t-2})+\varepsilon_t.$$ The lag order 2 was selected for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @RichardHardy, I thought OP said he only needs tomorrow's price, i.e. 1-step ahead

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you. I just want to forecast one step ahead actually as Aksakal has mentioned.

Comment: @Aksakal, OK, then it's fine. I did not say you were wrong. I just pointed out the benefit of having the whole VECM, namely, that it facilitates multi-step-ahead forecasting.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you again for all the help. Should I then look to use the model that we discussed on the other thread where I forecast each of the exogenous variables through ARIMA Models, of course carrying out the differencing associated with cointegration? So, would the equation now be $$\log(C_{t})= \alpha_1*\log(C_{t−1})+\alpha_2*(\log(O_{t})-\log(O_{t-1}))+\alpha_3*(\log(H_{t})-\log(O_{t}))+\\\alpha_4*\log(L_{t})-\log(O_{t}))+\alpha_5*N_{t}+ε_{t−1}?$$ All the variables at $t$ would be predicted via ARIMA forecasts.

Comment: I see that I forgot subscripts for the error correction terms in my comment from 7 hours ago. All of the error correction terms should have time subscripts $_{t-1}$. Your last suggestion is not something I find intuitive, but you could try it as an alternative to a full VECM or one equation of the full VECM; I do not immediately see a reason why it should fail.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for all your help. I have learnt a lot through this process. Do you think it is possible that there are not enough degrees of freedom, despite there being **11** constants whose values need to be found and **21** data points?

Comment: @RichardHardy Also, with regards to the model I described in my comment above, does it not make sense to have endogenous variables which are at time $t$ too? This is why I thought they would need to be predicted via ARIMA models and the ones at $t-1$ would already be known.

Comment: I sort of get your idea, it's just that the model equation does not look familiar. It is quite similar to one equation of a VECM. Perhaps the main difference is that you use univariate ARIMA models instead of VECM for $O$, $H$ and $L$. 21 data points and 11 coefficients to be estimated should not cause the problem of running out of degress of freedom. (It would be relevant if you had more than 21 coefficient to estimate with only 11 data points.) I think the comments are getting too extensive, pehaps it could be more useful for you to post new separate questions for each issue, or use chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30789/discussion-between-jojo-and-richard-hardy).